# How does integrating a function lead to itself?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm new to calculus, so sorry if I worded the question incorrectly. I am studying for a general maths exam, where I need calculus, which I won't study at school.

In any case, I stumbled across the following problem:

> For every real $x$ the equation  $$ 6 + f(x) = 2f(-x) + 3x^2
>  \int_{-1}^{1}f(t) \, dt $$  is true. What is the value of  $$
>  \int_{-1}^{1} f(x) \, dx $$

After working on the problem for 15+ minutes I gave up and looked at the solution. It said that I need to first integrate both sides and I should get the following:

$12 + \int_{-1}^{1}f(x)dx = 2\int_{-1}^{1}f(-x)dx + [x^3]_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)dx$

And the problem is simple onwards. I understand how everything on the left side integrates to what the solution says, as well as the first member on the right side. But how does $\int_{-1}^{1}f(t)dt$ become $\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)dx$? Shouldn't they be equal? How does one become the other after integration?

Comment: They are the same.  The writer just changed the dummy variable from $t$ to $x$.

Comment: If in doubt you can study the definition of a definite integral.

Comment: @lulu Yeah, I understand that. The problem is how integrating the integral of f(x) becomes the integral of f(x)...

Comment: That definite integral is just a constant.  It comes out of the second integral.

Comment: @lulu But isn't the integral of some constant c c*x? Shouldn't the second integral then be the first one times x?

Comment: Let $L=\int_{-1}^1 f(t)dt$.  Then the second term on the right is just $3Lx^2$.  We then remark that $\int_{-1}^1 3Lx^2dx=3L\int_{-1}^1 x^2dx$

Comment: @lulu That's genius, I never thought of that. Thanks. You may rewrite it below, so I can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The definite integrals $\int_{-1}^1 f(t)\,dt$ and $\int_{-1}^1 f(x)\,dx$ *are the same* -- the name of the dummy variable is not visible outside a definite integral.

Comment: @HenningMalkolm Yes, I understand that. The problem is that we integrate everything on the first line in order to get the second line. That includes the definite integral of f(t), which is the same as the one for f(x), and the result is the definite integral of f(x).

Answer (score 1):

The integral from -1 to 1 over f is just a scalar, no function. Write it down with t instead of x in the last integral, then it should make a lot more sence and would also be more precise. After gaining the value of the t integral fron taht equation, you can use the fact, that the value of the integral is the same, no matter how you name the integrated variable.